# Informix ODBC driver exception in Windows 2008

Tags: asp.net

I have .NET 4.0 project with Informix 64 ODBC driver connection works fine at my local( which is windows 7) but when I deploy the project on server which is windows 2008 (64 bit version) with Informix ODBC driver(64 bit version) then application throws exception 
***Unable to find an entry point named 'InterlockedIncrement' in DLL 'kernel32.dll'.*** 
I already read thread about the same error but no help.

I would appreciate help in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually using 32 bit version instead of 64 and it was working because I set platform target to Any CPU in project settings so it was targetting 32 bit version. When I changed to 64 then exception on server is resolved. Also I added PATH environment variable as %INFORMIXDIR%\bin and 
%INFORMIXDIR%\bin\netf20.